# Implement using inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have a problem and I want to resolve it using Inheritance and Polymorphism with C++:

- An **Equipment** may be a **cut-off device** or a **cable**
- Every **Equipment** has an identifier N
- the **cut-off device** has a position : OPEN or CLOSED
- the **cable** has a length L
- Every **Equipment** has a resistance:

  - NULL for a cut-off device
  - coefficient 0.5 of the length for a cable

I had made this implementation with C++ classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Phy{
    protected :
        float resistance;
    public:
        virtual void updateResistance() = 0;
`       float getResis(){return resistance;}
};
class Organe: public Phy{
    protected :
        int position;
    public:
        Organe(int pos):position(pos){};
        virtual void updateResistance(){resistance = 0;};
        int GetPos()const{return position;}
};
class Cable: public Phy{
    protected :
        float longeur;
    public:
        Cable(float longeu):longeur(longeu){};
        virtual void updateResistance(){resistance = 0.5 * longeur;};
        float Getlong()const{return longeur;}
};

class Equipement: public Organe, public Cable{
    protected :
        int id;
    public:
        Equipement(int idd, float longe = 0,  int pos =0):id(idd),Cable(longe), Organe(pos){};
        int GetId()const {return id;}
        float GetResistance(){ return resistance;}
};

int main(){
    Equipement Equip(25, 20, 0);
    Equip.GetResistance();
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the main, I have an error : "GetResistance is ambiguous"
Also, I have doubts about my architecture, there is any conception error?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! Please show some insight into what you have tried already. What code do you have, what specific problems did you encounter?`

Comment: I guess you mean `ambiguous access of 'resistance'`? Because `GetResistance` is not ambiguous.

Comment: You have the inheritance reversed. `Equipment` should be the base class; `Cable` and `Organe` are specializations of it, so they need to be the subclasses. As it currently is written, Equipment is both a Cable and an Organe (both at the same time). or basically remove the current Equipment class, and then rename `Phy` to `Equipment`.